# Ubuntu in external hard drive boots in laptop but doesn't in PC

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

i'm completely new to Ubuntu, i have to install it for university. (Anyway i already hate it xD). After several unsuccessfull installations i've been able to install version 15 in my external hdd. Now when i insert that hdd in my portable and i change boot settings from bios i'm able to run Ubuntu correctly, while if i start the external hard drive from my pc it just jumps it and starts the next hard drive available.
My pc has an Asus Crosshair V Formula-Z motherboard with usb3 ports as the portable has. 
How do i solve this issue?

EDIT:
The point is thet i need to use it on both computers; works perfectly in the protable, the only missing thing is making it run on the PC. Don't want dual boot actually: when the external hdd isn't inserted i don't want my computer to look for it; i'll just destroy ubuntu after university xD

Comment: Are your machines both UEFI or both BIOS?  How did you set up the external HDD to boot (UEFI or BIOS or both)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you installed ubuntu from your notebook(or whatever) it has saved your HW configuration, so it'll only run on machine you used to install it.

If you need to run system that is installed on one medium on multiple PCs, you need to choose some portable distro, they are designed exactly for that.

I don't knou what exactly you want it for, but you could use Ubuntu install disk with some persistence.

Anyway, the easiest way is still installing it as dual-boot on both machines, it is easy and on internet there are many manuals.

Comment: The kernel will detect hardware upon boot and will run on any system, not only the machine you installed it on. This is most probably a BIOS/UEFI/bootloader issue.